# using self.method_name inside a class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-unittest

I'm new to **OOP** in **Python**. I'm using the `unittest` package for the first time. In the code below, which is from Python official documentation, when we use `self.assertEqual` are we calling the `assertEqual` method from the base class `unittest.Testcase`?

In general, whenever we call `self.method_name` inside another method definition of a class, does it call the method from the base class (assuming that `method_name` is not defined for the derived class)?

```
import random
import unittest

class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.seq = list(range(10))

    def test_shuffle(self):
        # make sure the shuffled sequence does not lose any elements
        random.shuffle(self.seq)
        self.seq.sort()
        self.assertEqual(self.seq, list(range(10)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in the [documentation for `unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.html#test-cases), `assertEqual` is a method provided by the `TestCase` class.

In general, when a method is accessed (via `self.<method_name>`) the base classes are then searched for that method using the [`MRO`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-method-resolution-order) or method resolution order for that specific class.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!